# Excel::Writer::XLSX separating column with bold border

Tags: perl

I've worked with the Excel::Writer::XLSX module to build a lot of spreadsheets, but  I was wondering if there is a way to basically separate certain columns with a bold border.  In my script I use a merge range of columns, so for example, C-E is merged, F-H, etc...  So I would like to put a bold divider along the E column, the H column, etc...  I think it would be some kind of add_format, however I'm already using an add_format to get the date centered, the headers rotated 90 degrees, etc.  Here is a quick snapshot of what I'm talking about (this is what I'm trying to copy via perl).

[image]

Comment: `set_border()` could be set on every cell within a column